# MS SQL. Не работает запрос с параметром

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть хранимка. Используется для поиска. По дефолту параметрам ставлю `'%'` и в запросе соответственно `like`. Но вот если без параметра выполнять, то все нормально, а если с ним, то пустая таблица. Код:

```
select * from Table where field1 like '%'
```

все норм

```
declare @param1 char (12) = '%'
select * from Table where field1 like @param1
```

пустая таблица.
Чую что что-то банальное, но понять не могу(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тип данных `char` фиксированной длины и дополняется пробелами. Выполним следующее:

```
declare @param1 char (12) = '%';
select concat('"',@param1,'"')

Результат: "%           "
```

Вот ваш запрос после этого и ищет поля оканчивающиеся на 11 пробелов.

Замените тип данных на varchar:

```
declare @param1 varchar (12) = '%';
select concat('"',@param1,'"')

Результат: "%"
```

Comment: Точно! Спасибо.